# Limiting innerhtml details display upto a particular date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Iam having a calendar with structure as follows.

```
<td class="fc-day fc-mon fc-widget-content fc-future fc-first" data-date="2014-05-12"></td>
<td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2014-05-13"></td>
<td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-future" data-date="2014-05-14"></td>
```

and i dynamically add contents to the `innerHTML` of the `td`.Below is the code to insert a value in the td.

The function `appendinnerhtml()` below is used to append the innerhtml of the td. I want append to work on td only before the data-date.

```
function appendinnerhtml(newtitle,newdays)
{       
    var specl=newtitle.split("@");
    var newres=specl[0]+'<br />'+specl[1]+'<br />';  
    var Newspltdays=newdays.split(",");

    for (var c=0;c<Newspltdays.length;c++)
    {
        $('.fc-day').css('height', 144+'px');
        var items = newres,
        divs = document.querySelectorAll('td.fc-'+Newspltdays[c]);
        [].slice.call(divs).forEach(function (div) {
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + items;
        });
    }

}
```

It is working fine. But my **problem** if i passed a `innerHTML` to `fc-tue` , it applies to all tuesdays of every month. I want this to show only upto a particular date.

**Reference image attatched**
[image]

Comment: post more code so that we can work on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traverse through the table.Check whether the date is right place to append. If so append your item.Check this below code

```
$('.fc-border-separate tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
var eachday=$(this).attr("data-date"); //here you will get date on each td

var d1 = Date.parse(eachday);
var d2 = new Date("2014-05-09");

if(d1 <= d2)
{

$(this).append(items); //here you can append your item to td
});
}

}); //traversing through td ends here
}); //traversing through tr ends here
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `data-date` attribute value provided in the table for comparison with the date  limit you require.
You can extract the date by `$("td fc-tue").attr("data-date")` and then covert it to date object for comparison

```
var d2 = Date.parse("12/05/14")    // Your required date

[].slice.call(divs).forEach(function (div) {
        var d1 =  Date.parse(div.attr("data-date"))
    if(d1 < d2) // check if the date is less than required date 
          div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + items;
});
```

Comment: I edited d1 as var d1 =  Date.parse($("td.fc-"+Newspltdays[c]).attr("data-date")); and it works